# Comparing generic interface types

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I need to detect whether an object of type `IDictionary<string, string>` is an `IDictionary<,>` and I'm having trouble coming up with the proper comparison logic.

I have tried the following:

```
typeof(IDictionary<string, string>)
       .GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>).Name);
```

and

```
typeof(IDictionary<string, string>)
       .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
       .GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>).Name);
```

Calling `typeof(Dictionary<string,string>).GetInterface(comparisonType.Name)` returns the expected non-null result, but if I compare on the `IDictionary<string,string>` type, `GetInterface()` returns null. Likewise, comparing on the GenericTypeDefinition also returns null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = typeof(IDictionary<string, string>);
        var y = typeof(IDictionary<,>);

        Console.WriteLine(x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == y);
    }
```

returns true